# How to truncate query results with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a brand search. I want an adjustment to the query view to be displayed. In the example image below, I am searching for `Meto` brand, so I display the search results also under the name `Meto`. I want to display only the first character, if I search for `Meto`, it will only show the letter `M`.

How to do that with javascript?

[image]

**My Template**

```
<div class="brands-list">
    @for ((key, val): brandsByFirstChar) {
        <div class='brand-by-alphabet'>
            <h3 class='alphabet' id='alpha-@key'>@key</h3>
            <div class="row brand-collection-container">
                <div class='col-sm-3 brand-collection'><ul>
                    @for ((i, b): val) {
                        <li><a href="/search?srp-brandIds=@b.getId()&srp-actionTrigger=BRAND&srp-brandMode=true">@b.getName()</a></li>
                    @if ((i.index() % 1) == 0) {    
                        </ul>
                </div> 
                <div class='col-sm-3 brand-collection'><ul>
                    }
                }
                </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
```

**My JS**

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#store-searchText", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        window.location = location.href.replace(location.search, '') + "?q=" + inputVal
    }
});
```

Comment: What language is this `@for ((key, val): brandsByFirstChar)`?  - looks like you should do it there (server side?)  in `@key` - eg `@key[0]` or `@key.substring(0,1)` or whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

For a js solution, you could change all `h3.alphabet` to replace with just the first character.

Using the .text overload with a function callback calls .text with each elements text in turn.

*However* you will get the FOUC (flash of unstyled content) as the page loads *then* runs your javascript - this would be best changed server-side (in the template)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".brands-list h3.alphabet").text(function(i, txt) {
    return txt.substr(0, 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brands-list">
  <div class='brand-by-alphabet'>
    <h3 class='alphabet'>Bosch</h3>
    <div class="row brand-collection-container">
      <div class='col-sm-3 brand-collection'>
        <ul>
          <li>Bosch</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class='alphabet'>Metro</h3>
    <div class="row brand-collection-container">
      <div class='col-sm-3 brand-collection'>
        <ul>
          <li>Metro</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you made an *ajax* call instead of reloading the page, you could intercept the html and amend it before it's displayed.